# What makes certain interfaces faster than others?

Tags: usb, pci-express, thunderbolt, hardware-acceleration

Basically I'm just wondering is why a PCIe 16x transmits data faster than say a Thunderbolt 2 cable, or why USBC is faster than USB 3.0.

What aspect of these cables (I don't really know what to call them ) allows them to transmit data quicker than other cables Andes there a way to limit this bottleneck?

Thanks.

Comment: What do ports have to do with your question?

Answer (score 2):

Because cable diameters, dimensions and cable quality matter when you get to high speed signalling.  PCIe has very tight tolerances on track widths and distances to other layers in the PCB resulting in signals that have very precise timing and minimal reflections and noise.

Similar requirements are placed on cables. Older cables have poorer tolerances and lower quality materials resulting in signals that are noisy, and as a result necessarily slow in order to ensure that the data is transferred correctly.

Answer (score 2):

PCIe 16x has 16 lanes for data per a device (card), **running in parallel**. Each lane is running at 2.5Gbps/5/8/16Gbps (depending on implemented version of the interface, v1x - v4x). It makes the throughput of the latest PCIe 16x v.4.0 interface effectively at 256Gbps.

Thunderbolt-3 is designed with two bi-directional lanes for up to 10 Gbits/s raw rate per lane, with up to total 20 Gbps full duplex **over two lanes in parallel**, and 40Gbps one-way for video display applications.

USB Type-C is not "faster" than USB3.0. However, USB3.1 Gen2 data rate (10Gbps) is faster than Gen1 speed (5Gbps), all over a single full-duplex data lane. All these rates can be implemented over Type-C connector, including all USB2.0 legacy rates. So it is incorrect to equate "Type-C" with USB3.1 Gen2 speed alone. USB3 uses only **one lane**.

So you naturally have 256 > 20 >10 >5 for PCIe16x ->Thunderbolt3 ->USB3.1_Gen2 -> Gen1 lineup of interfaces.

What limits the data transfer rate over a single lane/cable? The maximum data transfer rate depends on quality/robustness of signal encoding in the channel (pre-emphasis and eqilization, link training, 8B/10B or 128b/132b encoding, etc.), and amount of effort devoted to quality of cable interconnect (uniformity of transmission lines, low signal loss, low cross-talk, and interface impedance matching across connectors). This means cost.

For the PCIe all transmission line matching can be done at simulation level within a single mainboard with well-characterized slot connectors, all under control of one developer. With shorter trace length and standardized matched layout of add-on cards, this allows for faster data rate per channel, currently at 16Gbps (GT/s).

When longer distances are involved, and third-party manufacturers (of cables) are involved, resulting reliability of transmission on realistic cable-connector combinations decreases, and the data rates have to be decreased.